# Why do I get this ImportError although python says the module is present?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

I'm confused as to the following repl interaction:

```
In [7]: import os

In [8]: os.sys
Out[8]: <module 'sys' (built-in)>

In [9]: os.sys.stderr
Out[9]: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>

In [10]: from os.sys import stderr
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-cd47f2925e40> in <module>()
----> 1 from os.sys import stderr

ImportError: No module named 'os.sys'; 'os' is not a package
```

How can it be that the python 3.5.3 states that `os.sys` is a module, but when trying to import it, raises an error?

P.S.: I am aware, that to access the error stream, I need to `import stderr` `from sys`, but I am confused regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `os` module actually imports `sys`, so the `sys` module is accessible thru `os.sys` (like any name defined at the module's top level). This doesn't make `sys` a proper submodule of `os` so you cannot import from `os.sys`.

As a side note, the fact that `os` imports `sys` is an implementation detail that you should not rely on.

Comment: re "This doesn't make sys a submodule of os so you cannot import it from os" - you can import sys from os, try `from os import sys` in your repl. What you cannot do is to use `os.sys` as a module. e.g. import from `os.sys`.

Comment: @khachik yes sorry my answer was very poorly worded on this point - I've edited it, thx for the constructive criticism.

Comment: What I find strange is that the interpreter claims `os.sys` is a module. Maybe the term *module*  means something other than I would expect, as apparently not everything which is a module can be imported.

Comment: @oarfish there's indeed some polysemy here... There's the module as "something - usually but not necessarily a .py file - that can be imported" and the runtime module as "an instance of the `module` type that has been created by an import".

Answer (score 1):

You haven't imported `os.sys`. You have only accessed the symbol. The `from ... import ...` statement is trying to access a part of the interpreter that doesn't have the data in it. (Most likely, `sys.modules`.)

Try doing `import os.sys` before repeating your command.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules['os']
>>> <module 'os' from '/.../lib/python3.5/os.py'>
sys.modules['os.sys']
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'os.sys'
```

Also, `os.sys` seems to be an alias for the `sys` module. There is no valid import of it, and

```
>>> import sys
>>> os.sys == sys
>>> True
```